# React JS API JSON pull setting booleans to display

Tags: javascript, reactjs, boolean, fetch-api

I am doing an API pull in React and have two booleans which I want to display their values. when I look at the console log, the values say "true" and "false" but they don't display in the UI. Is there a way to display the boolean values of "true" and "false"? New to JS.

```
 constructor(props) {
            super(props);
            this.state = {
                isLoaded: false,
                items: [],
                callToggleState: false,
            }
            
        }
    
    componentDidMount() {
        fetch(url , {
            method: 'get',
            mode: 'cors',
            headers: { 
            'X-API-KEY': API_KEY,
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            }
    
        })
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(json => {
              console.log(json);
                this.setState({
                    isLoaded: true,
                    items: json,
                  
                })
            })
        };
////////////////////////////////////////

return (
                <div className="container">
                 <ul>
                    {items.map((dynamicItem) => (
                        <li key={dynamicItem.device_id}> 
<li>
//////////////////////////////////////
</li>
```

Comment: Yes.. do a test like `{val === 'true' ? true : false}` in UI when printing

Comment: Can you show the code, from where you try to print those values..

Comment: it should be `{dynamicItem.boolValue ? "true" : "false"}`

Comment: {dynamicItem.boolValue ? "true" : "false"} worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a conditional rendering as @xadm suggested in the comments.

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    items: [
      { device_id: 1, name: "foo", bool: true },
      { device_id: 2, name: "bar", bool: false },
      { device_id: 3, name: "baz", bool: true },
    ]
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <ul>
        {
          this.state.items.map( dynamicItem =>
            <li>
            ID: {dynamicItem.device_id}<br />
            Name: {dynamicItem.name }<br />
            Bool: {dynamicItem.bool ? "true" : "false"}
            { /* or maybe? */}
            { /* Bool: {dynamicItem.bool ? "available" : "not in stock"} */}
            </li>
          )
        }
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```